# Gradle does not update snapshot dependencies

Tags: gradle, nexus

I have a gradle project that has a dependency on another gradle project.  The dependency is being published to our in-house nexus server and can be resolved just fine.

Once the dependency has been cached locally I cannot get it to be refreshed unless I pass in --refresh-dependencies to the gradle command (or delete it manually from the cache).

Having searched the internet I found a lot of people with the same problem and the suggestion was to mark the dependency as changing (although this is not strictly necessary as it is implicit from the name -SNAPSHOT) and to add this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

however this does not work for me, it will always used the cached version until the gradle default 24 hours is up and then it will re-download it.

Does anyone have any idea what else I may be missing, or how I can diagnose what gradle is doing and why it is not going to nexus to download new versions?

Comment: Well, the `--refresh-dependencies` option is there exactly for this reason.

Comment: But that refreshes all of the dependencies not just the SNAPSHOTs, so it's not what I want to do as it renders the cache meaningless.

Comment: Does it help to explicitly mark the dependency as changing ? `compile ('groupId:artifactId:X.X.X-SNAPSHOT'){
    changing=true
}`

Comment: No, this does not help in my case.

Comment: This should work as is. Can you please provide the dependency declaration in question. Also try to run with `-i` for more information on what's going on under the covers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that the reason the feature wasn't working as expected was because we were using the `spring-boot` plugin. The `spring-boot` plugin uses its own dependency management plugin which has its own configuration for the changing modules:

```
dependencyManagement {
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }
}
```

Adding this snippet to the gradle file forces changing modules to always be downloaded.

Comment: This has been a life saver for me. We were using SNAPSHOT builds, and on refresh dependencies we could only see the binary jar to be downloaded and not the source jar. Now it works perfectly. Thank you!!

Comment: God bless you, I spent a lot of time to fix this problem.